# Build only ChangeSet using MSBuild in Visual Studio Online

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops, changeset

I have set up a Build Definition to build a solution on Visual Studio Online (VSO). It's working fine, but it builds all the code every time when I check in the code.

How can I build a particular changeset from the code?

How can I use/pass this number to the "MSBuild Arguments" to use it there for deployment?

Comment: Which build system are you using? v-Next or XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the CI build feature(Uncheck "Continuous integration (CI)" option under "Triggers" tab in your build definition) if you don't want it to build all the code every time when you check in.

To build a particular changeset, you can enter the changeset number in "Source Version" textbox when you queue a new build. (In Git, it is "Commit" textbox)[image]

To pass the version number to MSBuild Arguments, you can use the pre-defined variable "$(Build.SourceVersion)", it is filled with the source version number you specified when you queue the build.

Comment: Thanks, But i would like to automate this process since i dont want to pass the changeset value every time while Queue the build. Please suggest me.

Comment: @ManojSharma Can you add more details about this? Like when you'd like to trigger a build and how to you determine which changeset to build?

Comment: On every code check-in i would like to trigger a build but it will build only changeset id. Now what is happening all the code build every check-in. But i would like to build only change set.

Comment: @ManojSharma There is no way to build only the changes in the changeset. When you queue a build, the whole project (all the code) must be built together. For example, in the changeset, you may change 1 line of code, but it is impossible to build this change only. Other unchanged code is need when build the project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could it be possible to deploy only change-set instead of full build deployment?

Comment: @ManojSharma Actually, you can use "Incremental Build" to achieve the feature you want, refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833876.aspx